# Get the result of an async task in C#, Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, async-await

I have the following lines of code which check if a device is registered in a database using an async method.

```
if (CrossConnectivity.Current.IsConnected)
{
      return await App._deviceService.GetDevice(id);
}
```

I had assumed that the await would have done just that - waited on GetDevice completing then return it's value, but on looking into I think that I need to use a callback if I want to get the actual result of the call so I can act upon it.

Can anyone tell me if I'm going down the correct route with this?  Below is the called async task

```
public async Task<bool> GetDevice(string deviceID)
{
    string url = Resources.Urls.dev + Resources.DeviceApi.Get + "?id=" + deviceID;
    HttpResponseMessage result;
    result = await App.HttpClientInstance().GetAsync(url);

    if (result.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, actually using `await` on call of method defined like this (`Task<bool>`) means the caller will "wait" for the return value to be ready, so your `return` will either return `true` or `false` based on the result of `GetDevice` call.

**Update**: I am clarifying that the code does not actually actively **wait** for the method to complete, because that would defeat the purpose of the `async/await` combo, but I meant that the `return` statement will execute only after the method actually completes. While the `HttpClient` request runs, the calling thread is free to do other tasks in the meantime, which is the true advantage of using `async/await`.

Comment: so what I have in the fist code snippet should return the desired true / false?

Comment: "No, actually using await on call of method defined like this (Task<bool>) means the thread will wait for the return value to be ready" - that is so **not** what `await` usually means... I'm willing to accept that it might behave differently in `Xamarin` (although I frankly doubt it) - but in general: `await` *does not* "wait" - that's kinda the entire point of `await`

Comment: Yes, it should :-) . But the caller has to have a return type of `Task<bool>`

Comment: @MarcGravell I meant the "waiting" in very high-level view. The `return` will execute only after the awaited method's is `Task` complete. It is not active waiting, because the thread is free to do anything else while the `HttpClient` request runs.

Comment: @MarcGravell You are absolutely right, that I accidentaly used the "thread will wait" there, which does not make sense.

Comment: @MartinZikmund ah, fair enough; if you mean *conceptually* wait in a loose sense - then: yes; obviously what it *actually* does is far more interesting :)

Answer (score 1):

```
return await App._deviceService.GetDevice(id);
```

This will return whatever `GetDevice` returns (`true` or `false`). You don't need to do anything further as you are already `await`ing for the `Task` to complete.

A minor suggestion would be to change your `GetDevice` return to

```
return result.IsSuccessStatusCode;
```

So that you don't depend directly on `200` but rather `2xx` (any success code).